# How to run a Spring Boot WAR app in Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, heroku

I've deployed a Spring Boot Web App to Heroku, but the app doesn't start, someone could help me?

It's my first time with Spring Boot and I guess I'm missing some necessary configuration in pom.xml

I have heroku/jvm buildpack in my application, but I noticed a heroku/java there too. Which one I should use for .war apps?

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Condominio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Condomínio App</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>myapp</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

CMD I used: `mvn clean heroku:deploy-war`

Result was

```
-----> heroku-maven-plugin app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 98.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v59
       https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Log:

```
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946295+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 16, 2018 2:00:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946299+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946303+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946305+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946307+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946309+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946311+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946313+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946314+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946316+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946318+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946319+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946321+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946323+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946328+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946330+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946331+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: app/condominio/CondomínioApplication
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946333+00:00 app[web.1]:    at app.condominio.ServletInitializer.configure(ServletInitializer.java:10)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946336+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:121)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946338+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946340+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946341+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946343+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946345+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946346+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.condominio.CondomínioApplication
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946348+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946349+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946351+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 12 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.946353+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948495+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 16, 2018 2:00:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948497+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948499+00:00 app[web.1]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948501+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948503+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948504+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948506+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948508+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948510+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948511+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948513+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948515+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948517+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:366)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948518+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:289)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948520+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948522+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948523+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948525+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948527+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948529+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948530+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948532+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948533+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948535+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948537+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948538+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948540+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948542+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948544+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948546+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948548+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948549+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 8 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948551+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948553+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948554+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948556+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: app/condominio/CondomínioApplication
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948558+00:00 app[web.1]:    at app.condominio.ServletInitializer.configure(ServletInitializer.java:10)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948560+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:121)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948561+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948563+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948565+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948566+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948568+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948570+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.condominio.CondomínioApplication
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948571+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948574+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948575+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 12 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.948577+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-16T02:00:55.949409+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.949542+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.949628+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:366)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.949750+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:289)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.949916+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950046+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950136+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950271+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950385+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 2 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950558+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950643+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.950899+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951072+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951244+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 4 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951458+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951578+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951662+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951776+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951852+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.951981+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952098+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952205+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952320+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952427+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 8 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952525+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952648+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952777+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952861+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.952976+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953064+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953180+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953302+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953394+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953510+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953608+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953714+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953825+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.953956+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954062+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954180+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954270+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954374+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 8 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954512+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954601+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954715+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954841+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: app/condominio/CondomínioApplication
2018-09-16T02:00:55.954924+00:00 app[web.1]:    at app.condominio.ServletInitializer.configure(ServletInitializer.java:10)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955070+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:121)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955189+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955274+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955398+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955487+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955570+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955714+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.condominio.CondomínioApplication
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955799+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.955890+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
2018-09-16T02:00:55.956014+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 12 more
2018-09-16T02:00:55.957944+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 16, 2018 2:00:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
2018-09-16T02:00:55.957947+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-13697"]
2018-09-16T02:00:55.958702+00:00 app[web.1]: Sep 16, 2018 2:00:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
2018-09-16T02:00:55.958705+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-09-16T02:00:56.406351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-16T02:00:56.423732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: My guess is that you're hitting a Heroku bug by using non-ASCII characters in your class name. It's technically legal but probably not a great idea.

Comment: I also suspected it, I already did the change in the class name and I'm starting another deploy to see if it will solve

Comment: there might be conflicting in dependencies version seems as heroku maven plugin should be sufficient to deploy.

Comment: Can you try excluding from tomcat dependency from web: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

Comment: it was only the "í" character causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chrylis said, this is a Heroku's bug caused by the non ASCII character 'í'. I solved the problem by renaming class.